# IronPython & WPF. How to change Image.Source at runtime in code?

Tags: wpf, python-3.x, ironpython

If I had a XAML element:

```
<Image x:Name="img"  Source= "D:\test.gif" />
```

and I need to:

```
self.img.Source = ?
```

C# logic didnt help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of many ways is to create a BitmapImage from an Uri:

```
from System import Uri
from System.Windows.Media.Imaging import BitmapImage

uri = Uri("D:\\test.gif")
self.img.Source = BitmapImage(uri)
```

Comment: It perfectly works this way.TY. You mentioned this as one of many ways, so can you please share some other ways?

Comment: There are many examples on MSDN, StackOverflow and the rest of the web if you search for BitmapImage and BitmapFrame.